# Prove the function $f$ is continous at $x_0$ if and only if it is both right and left continous at $x_0$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

$f(x)$ is continous at the point $x_0$ to the left, if $\forall x_n \gt x_0 , (x_n) \to x_0 \implies f(x_n) \to f(x_0).$

$f(x)$ is continous at the point $x_0$ to the right, if $\forall x_n \lt x_0, (x_n) \to x_0 \implies f(x_n) \to f(x_0).$

How to show that this statement is true, when the above is true, and vica versa?

Heine definition for continuity: $f(x)$ is continuous at the point $x_0$, if $\forall x_n \to x_0 \implies f(x_n) \to f(x_0)\implies
f(x_n) \to f(x_0).$

Let $x_n \gt x_0,(x_n)\to x_0$, then $f(x_n) \to f(x_0)$. So, it is continuous at the point $x_0$ to the left.
So, if $x_n\gt x_0,$ and $(x_n)\lt x_0,$ and $(x_n) \to x_0, f(x_n) \to f(x_0)$.

I assume: f is right continuous and left continuous at $x_0$. Is f continuous at $x_0$? Suppose f is not continous at $x_0.$ Then, By definition there exists a sequence $(x_n)→x_0$ such that $(f(xn))$ does not converge to f(x0). But we know thatif $x_n \gt x_0, or (x_n) \lt x_0, or both, (x_n) \to x_0, f(x_n) \to f(x_0).$

And we know that if $x_n=x_0$ then $x_n \to x_0, f(x_n) \to f(x_0)$. So, for all of the sequences, $f(x_n) \to f(x_0)$. But we said, that there exists a sequence $(x_n)\to x_0$ such that (f(xn)) does not converge to f(x0). So this is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you, I have to think about it. It seems difficult to me. Too much notation. I will take a look at it. I started reading about this stuffs just recently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ then clearly we have that $f$ is right-continuous and left-continuous at $x_0$.

Conversely, assume that $f$ is is right-continuous and left-continuous at $x_0$. Is $f$ continuous at $x_0?$ We could argue by contradiction. Let suppose that $f$ is not continous at $x_0.$ By definition there exists a sequence $(x_n)\to x_0$ such that $(f(x_n))$ does not converge to $f(x_0).$ There are infinitely many $x_n$ which are smaller than $x_0$ or there are infinitely many $x_n$ which are bigger than $x_0$ (or both). In the first case $f$ is not left-continous at $x_0$ and in the second case $f$ is not right-continous at $x_0$ (or both).

Comment: I think I understand it. At least I hope so.

Comment: Thank you for editing. :) It looks better. I have to practice writing, the mathematical notation...